# Upload two distinct files in Mean stack

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, multer

how to upload to different files using multer? when i say two different files it does not mean multifile upload. Tried using upload.fields but it failed to upload. Would be thankful if someone could help me to resolve it.
[image: 1]

```
   schoolpass.component    

         <div class="col-md-4">
                <mat-label><strong>Signature</strong></mat-label>
      <div class="input-group">

  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" name="avatar" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
      aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>

              <div class="form-group">
        <div class="preview" *ngIf="preview && preview !== null">
          <img height="150px" width="150px" [src]="preview" [alt]="form.value.name">
        </div>
      </div>

</div>  


          <div class="col-md-4">
                <mat-label><strong>photo</strong></mat-label>
      <div class="input-group">

  <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" name="avatars" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile02"
      aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon02" (change)="uploadFiles($event)">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose file</label>
  </div>
</div>

              <div class="form-group">
        <div class="preview" *ngIf="preview1 && preview1 !== null">
          <img height="150px" width="150px" [src]="preview1" [alt]="form.value.names">
        </div>
      </div>

</div>
```

schoolpass.component.ts

```
      // Image Preview
              uploadFile(event) {
                const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
                this.form.patchValue({
                  avatar: file
                });
                this.form.get('avatar').updateValueAndValidity()
               // File Preview
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                  this.preview = reader.result as string;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
              }
              uploadFiles(event) {
                const files = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
                this.form.patchValue({
                 avatars: files
                });
                this.form.get('avatars').updateValueAndValidity()
               // File Preview
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = () => {
                  this.preview1 = reader.result as string;
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(files)
              }
```

this is my backend code
 schollpass.route.js

```
// Multer File upload settings
const DIR = './public/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, DIR);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
    cb(null, fileName)
  }
});

// Multer Mime Type Validation
var upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
    if (file.mimetype == "image/png" || file.mimetype == "image/jpg" || file.mimetype == "image/jpeg") {
      cb(null, true);
    } else {
      cb(null, false);
      return cb(new Error('Only .png, .jpg and .jpeg format allowed!'));
    }
  }
});


// User model
let Schoolpass = require('../models/Schollpass');


// POST User
router.post('/create-user', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res, next) => {
  const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host')
  const schoolpass = new Schoolpass({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    student_name: req.body.student_name,
    class_sec: req.body.class_sec,
    admission_no: req.body.admission_no,
    school: req.body.school,
    relation: req.body.relation,
    others: req.body.others,
    vehicletype: req.body.vehicletype,
    gate: req.body.gate,
    make: req.body.make,
    regno: req.body.regno,
    avatar: url + '/public/' + req.file.filename,
    avatars: url + '/public/' + req.file.filename
  });
  schoolpass.save().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    res.status(201).json({
      message: "User registered successfully!",
      schoolpassCreated: {
        _id: result._id,
        student_name: result.student_name,
        class_sec: result.class_sec,
        admission_no: result.admission_no,
        school: result.school,
        relation: result.relation,
        vehicletype: result.vehicletype,
        gate: result.gate,
        make: result.make,
        regno: result.regno,
        avatar: result.avatar,
        avatars: result.avatars
      }
    })
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err),
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show some code of what you have tried. The error messages you got when it "failed to upload"

Comment: What's the behaviour that you described as "failed to upload"? Do you see any error message? Or was the file simply not saved on disk? Also I don't see any logic on how you handle the file upload at the client side. You only showed how you get the files from the form

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your server code where you are using `upload.single('avatar')`, this will only support for single file upload.For multiple file upload in a single request you need to use `upload.array('avatars')`.

You need to pass the files from the client side as follows

```
// Assuming you have pushed the selected files to this.selectedFiles 

const formData: FormData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < this.selectedFiles.length; i++) {
  formData.append('avatars', files[i]);
}
// formData will also have other values as well along with avatars which you 
//need to append here before hitting the post req

this.http.post(<your url>, formData).subscribe()
```

Now on the server side the uplaoded files will be available to you in `req.files` , `files` will be the new property added to your `req` object by `upload.array('avatars')` middleware.

So you can simply pass it as

```
avatar: url + '/public/' + req.files[0].filename,
avatars: url + '/public/' + req.files[1].filename
```